# How to get 10 characters of Model Attribute value in jsp?

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, model

I Am trying to display 10 characters of model attribute value in JSP, 
The Below code is written in controller.java.

`model.addAttribute("mappingList",mappingList);`

Comment: What is mappingList ? If it is a `List` what does it contain ?

Comment: It is **List** of json object .

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved this issue using `jstl substring` where i can display only 10 characters of the object using below code.

```
${fn:substring(mappingList.sequence,0, 10)}
```